# Install ruby 2.1.5 via rbenv

Tags: centos, rbenv

I already have **rbenv** version **0.4.0-97-gfe0b243** installed, that manages ruby version 2.1.1

Now, I also want it to manage ruby 2.1.5

But, when I do `rbenv install --list` then I see max ruby **2.1.2** and then **2.2.0-dev**. What should I do for getting version 2.1.5 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code helped me get over the situation.

**GOTO**

```
cd ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build
git pull
```

Now I can see 2.1.5 also listed in `rbenv install --list`

Comment: OMG ... that's so sad I'm forced to use rbenv while rvm did this part so much better ... 

Answer (score 1):

You can perform an upgrade on ruby-build.

```
$ brew update
$ brew upgrade rbenv ruby-build
$ rbenv install --list
```

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** I have tested the following procedure on Ubuntu 16.04, it work for me. I am assuming that you have already installed the rbnev on your system successfully. To check is it working properly or not? run the command *rbenv -v* 
it will give you output like this.

rbenv 1.0.0-33-gc7dcaf1

**but in your System the version of rbenv version may be different**.

Run the following command to install required version of ruby.

- git clone https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build.git ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build
- echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
- exec $SHELL
- rbenv install --list
- select appropiate available of ruby as per your requirement 2.1.5
- rbenv install 2.1.5
- rbenv global 2.1.5
- rbenv rehash
- ruby -v